# Reset button erases sub-component input's value

Tags: angular, forms, angular-components

I separated a special input-row, since it is often used, so it's better to create a new component to handle all of its stuff separately. The problem is that when I press on a reset button, the text input's value that is located inside the new component isn't changed back to its original value, it's just removed. I guess it's because the input's value is dynamically wired to the component's input parameter, and the actual input field doesn't have `value="constant text"` attribute.

The page's HTML:

```
<form>
    <h3 class="form-group-caption"
        >Mappaútvonalak
        <input type="reset" class="ml-3 btn btn-light" value="Visszaállítás" />
    </h3>
    <app-stateful-text-input
        label="FRM"
        inputValue="A:\Temp"
        inputType="text"
        apiPath="/api/frm"
    ></app-stateful-text-input>
```

The component's HTML contains some wrapper elements, and:

```
<input
    type="{{inputType}}"
    class="form-control form-control-lg"
    id="input-{{label}}"
    value="{{inputValue}}"
    (keypress)='onInputChanged($event)'
/>
```

For one input, I could write a `resetInputs()` method, and call it when the reset button is pressed. However, there're a lot of instances of this new component, in multiple pages, anywhere inside forms. If I'd need to maintain references to all of them, just to be able call a method in that sub-component, I'd lose the key point of separating them.

Is there any simple solution to this situation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could make this automatic by adding a `reset` event listener to the container `<form>`, at that time I overwrite the `value` attribute with the stored one.

However, it's still ugly, this requires additional JS. I'd love a "native solution" where the reset button could do what it wants to.

```js
export class StatefulInputComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() inputValue: string;
    @ViewChild('inputField', {static: true}) inputField: ElementRef;
    defaultValue: string;
    ngOnInit() {
        this.defaultValue = this.inputValue;
        let element = this.inputField.nativeElement as HTMLElement;
        do {
            element = element.parentElement;
        } while (element != null && element.tagName !== 'FORM');
        if (element == null) {
            throw new Error('<app-stateful-input> must be placed inside a <form>!');
        }
        const form = element as HTMLFormElement;
        form.addEventListener('reset', (event: Event) => {
            const input = this.inputField.nativeElement as HTMLInputElement;
            input.value = this.defaultValue;
            event.preventDefault();
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you try to use a @HostListener? https://angular.io/api/core/HostListener
I haven´t use it with `reset`, but might work.

Answer (score 1):

You could set a default value in the Input component and use it with a `resetInputs()` method, as you suggest, in the parent component.

```
<app-stateful-text-input
        label="FRM"
        defaultValue="A:\Temp"
        inputType="text"
        apiPath="/api/frm"
    ></app-stateful-text-input>
```

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-stateful-text-input',
  template: `...`
})
export class StatefulTextInputComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() 
  public defaultValue: string;

  public inputValue: string;

  public ngOnInit(): void {
      this.inputValue = this.defaultValue;
  }
}
```

In your parent component you can iterate in all the children custom input and set the old value when resetting.

```js
@Component({
  selector: 'app-form-component',
  template: `...`
})
class FormComponent {
  @ViewChildren(StatefulTextInputComponent) statefulTextInputs: QueryList<StatefulTextInputComponent>;
  ...

  public resetInputs(): void {
     this.statefulTextInputs.forEach((item: StatefulTextInputComponent) => item.inputValue = item.defaultValue);
  }

  ...
}
```

Comment: The `@ViewChildren` is a good idea, but it's still manual and I'd need to add this to every parent component.